# Can't dismiss UISplitViewController presented modally in primaryOverlay mode

Tags: swift3, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a modally presented `UISplitViewController`, and added a IBAction button on master view controller to dismiss them all. When the `displayMode` is `allVisible`, it works just fine:

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But when the `displayMode` is `primaryOverlay`, the line of code above doesn't work. So I tried this:

```
self.navigationController?.splitViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but it only dismisses the detail view controller leaving the master.